# Java Comparator doesn't compare each object

Tags: java, comparator

I'm having a few complications with the Java `Comparator`. So I have a parent node that has a list of children. I want to sort those children, seems pretty simple on the face of it, however when the `Comparator` does the sorting it only checks certain objects against certain objects, then I suppose it infers the positions of objects, as to say if `a` is before `d`, `f` is after `d`, `b` is before `d` which means `b` is before `f`.

Below is an example of my current setup. I have a parent node `a` with 4 children nodes `b`, `e`, `l`, `g`. When I sort these children, I would expect the order to be `b`, `g`, `l`, `e`, so sorting by alphabet and always making sure a parent node comes first.

(Excuse the shoddy drawing)

[image]

Very simple, I have a `Node` class, it contains an ID, so it's letter and then a list of children.

```
public class Node {

    private char id;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();


    public Node(char id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public char getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((Node) obj).getId() == this.id;
    }
}
```

I then have the `NodeComparator` class which first checks if the nodes are your children and then if they are you go first, vice versa, then orders by alphabet.

```
    @Override
    public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
        if (o1.getChildren().contains(o2)) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (o2.getChildren().contains(o1)) {
            return 1;
        }

        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        int firstNodeIndex = -10;
        int secondNodeIndex = -10;
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
            if (alphabet.charAt(i) == o1.getId()) {
                firstNodeIndex = i;
            }
            if (alphabet.charAt(i) == o2.getId()) {
                secondNodeIndex = i;
            }
        }
        if (firstNodeIndex > secondNodeIndex) {
            return 1;
        } else if (firstNodeIndex == secondNodeIndex) {
            return 0;
        }else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when the sorting is done it checks:

```
E against B
G against E
L against G
```

So it never check L against E so it has no way of knowing that should come first.

Comment: When the sorting puts E before G and G before L, then it’s unavoidable that E is also before L. What’s your problem? Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: In your drawing you have both lower and upper case nodes, but in the code it looks like you assume they are all upper case. Are the actual node ids all upper case?

Comment: Do I read correctly that L is the parent of E and you always want the parent before its child? So would the correct sorting be A-B-G-L-E??

Comment: sorry yeah all upper case @Eran

Comment: yes @OleV.V. perfect

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use a comparator here, because not all nodes have direct relationships, which makes it difficult to ensure transitivity. Sounds to me like you just need a modified breadth-first traversal.

Comment: (Nice and clear drawing, BTW, it conveys your situation clearly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ordering violates `Comparator`'s contract:

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.

```
compare('G','E') > 0 // since 'G' comes after 'E' in the alphabet
```

and

```
compare('E','L') > 0 // since 'E' is a child of 'L'
```

but

```
compare('G','L') < 0 // since 'G' comes before 'L' in the alphabet
```

Since your `Comparator` is not a valid `Comparator`, it is likely to yield either an exception or unexpected results.

Comment: Okay thank you, it just yields unexpected results. So is the only solution to implement my own sorting?

Comment: @user3667111 you might have to do that. I'm not sure there can be a valid `Comparator` that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Good sorting algorithms try to minimize the number of compares for achieving good performance. This is not an issue but a feature of these sorting algorithms. It would not change the result if it would compare each element with each other element.

You should have a closer look at your Comparator if the ordering is not as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out your comparator violates the comparator contract... But doing your own sorting the way you describe you want it to work shouldn't be too complex, you probably want something like:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class NodeSorter {

    public void sort(List<Node> nodes) {
        Collections.sort(nodes, (x, y) -> Character.compare(x.getId(), y.getId()));
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                Node x = nodes.get(i);
                Node y = nodes.get(j);
                if (y.getChildren().contains(x)) {
                    nodes.remove(y);
                    nodes.add(i, y);
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also even if you want to keep your comparator for something you can remove half the logic from it by using Character.compare(), like:

```
@Override
public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
    if (o1.getChildren().contains(o2)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (o2.getChildren().contains(o1)) {
        return 1;
    }

    return Character.compare(o1.getId(), o2.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparisons that it makes are correct and what would be expected. If L > G and G > E then, according to the rules of comparitors, L > E.

Comparators follow the normal rules of arithmetic in this respect. 3 > 2 and 2 > 1 means 3 > 1 (transitivity).

Your problem is probably that E is a child of A. Normally, it shouldn't be in these kind of trees. Having more than one parent complicates tree handling considerably. If you remove that link and have some kind of recursive algorithm to do traverse the tree when you do the comparison, it should work.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what you mean by removing the link, if I remove the link it'll completely ruin the data

Comment: Without knowing what the data is, it is hard to say what you should do.